# Changing style of unnumbered chapters in memoir

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir

The MWE below illustrates that while I can center numbered chapter headings, I cannot do so for unnumbered chapter headings:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Numbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a [look](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) at how the chapter headings are printed (p. 82). `memoir` makes a distinction here. For unnumbered chapters, you'd need this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Numbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. Wouldn't it make more sense to call it \printchapternamenonum?